# Grouping by to find average differences for specific indexes in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following table:

```
person_index   score   year
3              76      2003
3              86      2004
3              86      2005
3              87      2006
4              55      2005
4              91      2006
```

I want to **group by person_index, getting the average score difference between consecutive years**, such that I end up with one row per person, indicating the average increase/decrease:

```
person_index   avg(score_diff)   
3              3.67      
4              36
```

So for person with index 3 - there were changes over 3 years, one was 10pt, one was 0, and one was 1pt. Therefore, their average score_diff is 3.67.

EDIT: to clarify, scores can also decrease. And years aren't necessarily consecutive (one person might not get a score at a certain year, so could be 2013 followed by 2015).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is to use `LAG`(MySQL 8.0+):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, score - LAG(score) OVER(PARTITION BY person_index ORDER BY year) AS diff
  FROM tab
)
SELECT person_index, AVG(diff) AS avg_diff
FROM cte
GROUP BY person_index;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de69b67cddd473e62271d95a09a38bd3)**

Output:

```
+---------------+----------+
| person_index  | avg_diff |
+---------------+----------+
|            3  |   3.6667 |
|            4  |  36.0000 |
+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: if you wanted to get the average annual increase per year rather than per person (meaning, from 2005 to 2006 you would have to average the two people, and previous years only one person, id = 3), could you still pull that using this code?

Answer (score 1):

If the scores only increase -- as in your example -- you can simply do:

```
select person_id,
       ( max(score) - min(score) ) / nullif(max(year) - min(year) - 1, 0)
from t
group by person_id;
```

If they do not only increase, it is a bit trickier because you have to calculate the first and last scores:

```
select t.person_id,
       (tmax.score - tmin.score) / nullif(tmax.year - tmin.year - 1, 0)
from (select t.person_id, min(year) as miny, max(year) as maxy
      from t
      group by person_id
     ) p join
     t tmin
     on tmin.person_id = p.person_id and tmin.year = p.miny join
     t tmax
     on tmax.person_id = p.person_id and tmax.year = p.maxy join
```